# regular expression to escape a single $ string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

Regarding the regular expression, in the below code its splits when str ^$$#$ is encountered. But the single $ should not change the way it is split.

ex:RefinementFilter$$#$TAGS_AND$$#$karen.bitran - LAD_ODA_IB SE < $10K

the above example should be split to 
refinement filter  TAGS_AND     karen.bitran - LAD_ODA_IB SE < $10K

but on encountering a single $, it cut the remaining string part and gives only a part of string

refinement filter  TAGS_AND     karen.bitran - LAD_ODA_IB SE <
which is not desired.

L_VALUE:=RefinementFilter$$#$TAGS_AND$$#$karen.bitran - LAD_ODA_IB SE > $10K FOR HR

```
WITH T AS
  (SELECT L_VALUE STR FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT MAX(DECODE(LEVEL,1,REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^($$#$)]+',1,LEVEL))) ,
  MAX(DECODE(LEVEL,2,REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^($$#$)]+',1,LEVEL))),
  MAX(DECODE(LEVEL,3,REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^($$#$)]+',1,LEVEL)))
INTO L_VAL1,
  L_VAL2,
  L_VAL3
FROM T
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^($$#$)]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Problem is in : ^. Notice that: \$\$\#\$ is going to find only this exact 'thing' and ignore single $. 
I recommend using: http://regexr.com/ 
it gives great possibilities to debug your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions `[]` signifies a **single** character match. So `[($$#$)]` would match a single character that is either `(` or `$` or `$` or `#` or `$` or `)` and negating `[^($$#$)]` that would match any character that is not `(`, `$`, `#` or `)`.

You can do this without regular expressions:

```
DECLARE
  pattern VARCHAR2(10)   := '$$#$';
  l_value VARCHAR2(4000) := 'abc$$#$def$$#$gh$i';
  l_val1  VARCHAR2(200);
  l_val2  VARCHAR2(200);
  l_val3  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  WITH string_matches (str, match_start, match_end, lvl ) AS (
    SELECT l_value, 1, INSTR( l_value, pattern, 1 ), 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT str,
           match_end + LENGTH( pattern ),
           INSTR( str, pattern, match_end + LENGTH( pattern ) ),
           lvl + 1
    FROM   string_matches
    WHERE  match_end > 0
  )
  SELECT str1, str2, str3
  INTO   L_VAL1, L_VAL2, L_VAL3
  FROM   string_matches
  PIVOT  ( MAX( SUBSTR(
                  str,
                  match_start,
                  DECODE( match_end, 0, LENGTH( str ) + 1, match_end ) - match_start
              ) )
           FOR lvl IN ( 1 AS str1, 2 AS str2, 3 AS str3 )
         );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_val1 );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_val2 );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_val3 );
END;
/
```

Or in pure PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
  pattern VARCHAR2(10)   := '$$#$';
  l_value VARCHAR2(4000) := 'abc$$#$def$$#$gh$i';
  matches stringlist := stringlist();
  match_start INTEGER := 1;
  match_end   INTEGER;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    match_end := INSTR( l_value, pattern, match_start );
    matches.EXTEND;
    IF match_end = 0 THEN
      matches( matches.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( l_value, match_start, LENGTH( l_value ) + 1 - match_start );
      EXIT;
    ELSE
      matches( matches.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( l_value, match_start, match_end - match_start );
    END IF;
    match_start := match_end + LENGTH( pattern );
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( matches(1) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( matches(2) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( matches(3) );
END;
/
```